# Passing configurable appInsights key to javascript (react/angular) app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

A am using Azure AppInsights with some ASP.NET Core 2.1 app. I keep instrumentation key in appsettings.json (which is later overridden by app config from Azure app service). Obviously the key can vary between environments (different on dev/qa/prod environments). That key is used by AppInsights SDK on the back-end side.

My question is: how can I pass that key to JavaScript/React app (to use it with JavaScript App Insisghts sdk)? I am not using Razor (and I don't want to) for generating the main page - its just static html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript">
         var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(a){
             function b(a){c[a]=function(){var b=arguments;c.queue.push(function(){c[a].apply(c,b)})}}var c={config:a},d=document,e=window;setTimeout(function(){var b=d.createElement("script");b.src=a.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js",d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(b)});try{c.cookie=d.cookie}catch(a){}c.queue=[];for(var f=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];f.length;)b("track"+f.pop());if(b("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),b("startTrackEvent"),b("stopTrackEvent"),b("startTrackPage"),b("stopTrackPage"),b("flush"),!a.disableExceptionTracking){f="onerror",b("_"+f);var g=e[f];e[f]=function(a,b,d,e,h){var i=g&&g(a,b,d,e,h);return!0!==i&&c["_"+f](a,b,d,e,h),i}}return c
         }({
             instrumentationKey: "how_to_populate_that_key?"
         });
         window.appInsights=appInsights,appInsights.queue&&0===appInsights.queue.length&&appInsights.trackPageView();
    </script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the proper solution for dynamically passing that key from backend to front-end? Should this be exposed by some endpoint? Or should I somehow dynamically generate some kind of script on the backend (that contains that key) and the reference it index.html?

I just don't want to just hard-code the key in JS codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Either calling API and load the Instrumentation Key before the app load or here is another way to load from the backend

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Standard Application Insights web page script:
var appInsights = window.appInsights || function(config){ ...
// Modify this part:
}({instrumentationKey:  
  // Generate from server property:
  "@Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey"
  }
 )
</script>
```

For more information go through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/separate-resources#web-pages